# Is there an equivalent of the lock{} statement for ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, readerwriterlockslim

I like the shortcut in C# of `lock(myLock){ /* do stuff */}`. Is there an equivalent for read/write locks? (Specifically ReaderWriterLockSlim.) Right now, I use the following custom method, which I think works, but is kind of annoying because I have to pass in my action as an anonymous function, and I would prefer to use a standard locking mechanism if possible.

```
    void bool DoWithWriteLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim RWLock, int TimeOut, Action Fn)
    {
        bool holdingLock = false;
        try
        {
            if (RWLock.TryEnterWriteLock(TimeOut))
            {
                holdingLock = true;
                Fn();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (holdingLock)
            {
                RWLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        return holdingLock;
    }
```

Comment: The *try* statement is in the wrong place.  Put it *after* TryEnterWriteLock().  No more need for a variable, a shortcut gets to be pointless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't override the behaviour of the `lock` keyword. A common technique is to hijack the `using` keyword.

1. Make `DoWithWriteLock` return an `IDisposable`
2. Keep the `TryEnterWriteLock` call inside the `DoWithWriteLock` method
3. Return an object that implements `IDisposable`. In that object's `Dispose` method, put the  call to `ExitWriteLock`.

The end result:

```
// Before
DoWithWriteLock(rwLock,
    delegate
    {
        Do1();
        Do2()
    } );

// After
using (DoWithWriteLock(rwLock))
{
    Do1();
    Do2();
}
```

Comment: before can be much better: `DoWithWriteLock(rwLock, () =>
    {
        Do1();
        Do2()
    } );`

Comment: Hi Tim.  Is it true this would be easier in F#?

Comment: Is there an analogous way to do this for TryEnterWriteLock with a timeout?

Comment: @jonnii F#'s `lock` function is essentially the OP's original `DoWithWriteLock`, but using `Monitor.Enter`: `lock syncRoot (fun () -> do1 |> do2)`

Comment: @Xodarap If you can work out a way to smuggle the result of `TryEnterWriteLock` out of the method at the same time as returning `IDisposable`. Maybe: `bool acquired; using (TryDoWithWriteLock(rwLock, out acquired)) {...}`

Comment: In the actual implementation, it's best to return a struct that publicly implements IDisposable (to avoid unnecessary heap allocations and/or boxing); see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/03/24/95743.aspx for background.